# How do XML processors handle unparsed entities?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Based on the research I've performed thus far, external unparsed XML entities are used to reference data that isn't necessarily XML. This provides a means of transferring non-XML data. As such, unparsed entities are dereferenced only in entity attributes since the dereferenced value will not conform to the structure of an XML document.

This all makes sense but I'm lost as to when/what dereferences the targeted file declared in the entity definition. Does the XML parser itself access the targeted file, extract the data, and then place it into the XML document? Or does the client, i.e. consumer of the XML document, access the data and act on it accordingly?

Admittedly, the issue could be that I have the XML processor I'm using (`Nokogiri::Version #=> "1.6.8.1"`) configured improperly but parsed external entities are successfully dereferenced.

Below is a bit of code to support my question:

*External DTD file hosted @ [http://127.0.0.1:81/some.dtd:](http://127.0.0.1:81/some.dtd:_)*

```
<!ELEMENT rootsies ANY>
<!ELEMENT arbitrary ANY>
<!ELEMENT viewer EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST viewer source ENTITY #REQUIRED>
<!ENTITY gif_source SYSTEM "file:///var/www/html/some.gif" NDATA gif>
<!NOTATION gif SYSTEM "text viewer">
<!ENTITY arbitrary_text "some text">
```

*XML File*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE rootsies SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1:81/some.dtd">
<rootsies>
    <viewer source="gif_source"/>
    <arbitrary>&arbitrary_text;</arbitrary>
</rootsies>
```

*Nokogiri Output*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE rootsies SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1:81/some.dtd">
<rootsies>
    <viewer source="gif_source"/>
    <arbitrary>some text</arbitrary>
</rootsies>
```

I figure I might as well post my rough harness at this point:

*Ruby Code*

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'nokogiri'

def print_errors(doc)

    if doc.errors != []

        ban = "Warning: Parse errors detected"

        puts
        puts "-" * ban.bytesize
        puts ban
        puts "-" * ban.bytesize
        puts doc.errors
        puts "-" * ban.bytesize
        puts

    end

end

# XML Parser Options (Nokogiri Options)
options = Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions.new()
options.recover
options.dtdload
options.noent
options.noblanks
options.dtdvalid # Uncomment to enforce DTD validation

# External DTD Example
ext_dtd = %`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE rootsies SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1:81/some.dtd">
<rootsies>
    <viewer source="gif_source"/>
    <arbitrary>&arbitrary_text;</arbitrary>
</rootsies>`

doc = Nokogiri::XML(ext_dtd, nil, nil, options)

print_errors(doc)

puts doc

print_errors(doc)
```